# FileSystemWatcher() not triggering on files encrypted in same directory

Tags: c#, encryption

I am building a little service that monitors a directory for an encrypted file using FileSystemWatcher.  The process flow is as follows:

- File gets moved/created in directory
- External process encrypts the file (creating a file with a *.pgp extension) in the same directory
- Service should then get triggered that the *.pgp file has been created

When the file in that directory gets encrypted, FileSystemWatcher is not triggering.  If I move the *.pgp file out/encrypt the file in a different location and then move it into the watched directory, FileSystemWatcher triggers.  Here is the relevant code:

```
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
                {
                    Path = _directory,
                    Filter = _filter,
                    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                                    NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
                                    NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                                    NotifyFilters.FileName |
                                    NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                                    NotifyFilters.Security |
                                    NotifyFilters.Size,
                };

                watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
                    //do stuff
        }
```

Is there anyway that I can pick up on this behaviour?  Or is this a limitation?

Thanks

Comment: How have you determined that it is not triggering? I ask because my first guess would be that it is triggering, but the event handler fails (due to the file still being in use). If you log the events before doing anything else, what do you see?

Comment: What value do you have in _filter variable? Try to catch the Created Event, instead of changed.

Comment: @hvd , its not running the tasks (the first of is a writeline) in the OnChanged block.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso , the filter is a *.pgp.  It works OK if I am detecting txt files, even if they are being written in that folder.  I'll look at the Created Event and see if that works.

Comment: @hvd, you're right - it was getting into the block, I was just not picking it up (writeline was in the wrong place).  Its all good, thanks for the reality check!  The issue is elsewhere